# Pygame - Prevent Sprite Overlap

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'll make this short and simple. In a side scrolling game, I have a sprite that the user controls, and a sprite that functions as the terrain. The environment sprite class, which in theory could be a floor, ceiling, or wall depending on it's location and which direction the player is colliding with it from, needs to do one thing: repel the player.

If the player collides with the top of an environment sprite, the player rests on the top border. If a player jumps and collides with the bottom of an environment sprite, they stop moving upwards and begin to fall. Logic right?

I can't figure it out. My first solution hopefully illustrates my problem (not actual code, just the problem area):

```
if player.rect.bottom > environment.rect.top:
    player.rect.bottom = environment.rect.top - 1
if player.rect.top < environment.rect.bottom:
    player.rect.top = environment.rect.bottom + 1
if player.rect.right > environment.rect.left:
    etc.
    etc.
    etc.
```

This works fine some of the time, but gets real dodgy at corners becase every overlap by more than 1px means two or more sides of the player are actually colliding with an environmental sprite at a time. This, in a nutshell, is the problem I face with every solution I've tried.

I've lurked every thread, tutorial,  video, blog, guide, faq, and help site I could reasonably and even unreasonably find on google, and I have no idea. Surely this is a thing someone has addressed before - I know it, I've seen it. I'm looking for advice, possibly a link, just anything to help me get over what I can only assume is a simple solution I can't find.

**How do you recalculate the positions of colliding sprites with respect to any and all directions?**

BONUS: I have gravity implemented too - or at least a near constant downward force. In case it matters.

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close with your solution.  Since you're using Pygame's rects to handle collision, I'll offer you the approach that suits them best.

It's not quite safe to make an assumption about how much one sprite is going to overlap another.  In this case, your collision resolution assumes a one pixel (probably better termed 'unit') overlap between your sprites, when in fact it sounds like you are getting more than that.  I'm guessing that your player sprite is not moving one unit at a time.

What you need to do then is determine the exact number of units your player has intersected an obstacle, and move him back by that much:

```
if player.rect.bottom > environment.rect.top:
    # Determine how many units the player's rect has gone below the ground.
    overlap = player.rect.bottom - environment.rect.top
    # Adjust the players sprite by that many units. The player then rests
    # exactly on top of the ground.
    player.rect.bottom -= overlap
    # Move the sprite now so that following if statements are calculated based upon up-to-date information.
if player.rect.top < environment.rect.bottom:
    overlap = environment.rect.bottom - player.rect.top
    player.rect.top += overlap
    # Move the sprite now so that following if statements are calculated based upon up-to-date information.
# And so on for left and right.
```

This approach should work even at convex and concave corners.  So long as you only need to worry about two axes, resolving each one independently will get you what you need (just make sure you're player can't get into an area he doesn't fit in).  Consider this brief example, where the player, `P`, is intersecting the environment, `E`, at a corner:

```
Before collision resolution:
--------
| P  --|------     ---  <-- 100 y
|    | |     | <-- 4px
-----|--  E  |     ---  <-- 104 y
     |       |
     ---------
      ^
     2px
     ^ ^
  90 x 92 x

Collision resolution:
player.rect.bottom > environment.rect.top is True
overlap = 104 - 100 = 4
player.rect.bottom = 104 - 4 = 100

player.rect.right > environment.rect.left is True
overlap = 92 - 90 = 2
player.rect.right = 92 - 2 = 90

After collision resolution:
--------
|  P   |
|      |
---------------- <-- 100 y
       |       |
       |    E  |
       |       |
       ---------
       ^
      90 x
```